# concatenate Combobox items from Oracle DB

Tags: vb.net, oracle, combobox

I want to display 2 table values from Oracle DB in combobox (name and surname). So far I can display only one, and this one also doesn't work with WHERE criteria.

```
 Using conn As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection("Data Source=MyDB;User Id=Lucky;Password=MyPassword;")

            Try

                conn.Open()

                Dim SQL As String
                NIZ = "SELECT Name,Surname from MyTable where ID=1 "
                Dim Cmd As New OracleCommand(SQL, conn)
                Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

                Dim dr As OracleDataReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()

                While (dr.Read())
                    CmbCustomers.Items.Add(dr.GetString(0))
                End While

                conn.Close()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Finally
                conn.Dispose()
            End Try
```

Anybody knows how I could display name and surname together in combobox, with WHERE clause ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using string concatenation  this way

```
 SELECT Name ||' ' || Surname from MyTable where ID=1
```

if you need alignment you can try padding

```
 SELECT Name || RPAD(' ', (12 - length(Name),' ') ||  '-  ' || Surname from MyTable where ID=1
```

Comment: Thanks scaisEdge, It works but everything so scrambled. Any options to allign texts?

Comment: I have update the answer with a suggestion for impreove alignment

Comment: no, i reduced to even 5, but not working, only 1 column is displayed now. And Its not name, surnames with "-" before only.

Comment: You mean exact same query as this or without rpad?

Comment: the exact query  with rpad .. SELECT rpad(Name, (12 - length(Name)), '*' ) || ' -  ' || Surname from MyTable where ID=1

Comment: That doesn't work in oracle, only without it like SELECT Name, Surname from MyTable where ID=1;

Comment: Error from where ? - Toad client(oracle) doesn't produce any, It just doesn't do the query.

Comment: Toad  .. should show the error message in message tab

Comment: Sorry, I misstyped. Toad works, no errors, but only 1 column also.

Comment: then  i can't   find other suggestion for better formatting the result

Comment: Tested, does the same as your original suggestion. both columns are shown, but text is scrambled. Concatenating in combobox with different text sizes is not nice. I guess I'll rather use Datagrid to display my table fields, and open it under Textbox to have simmilar look as combobox. Thanks for all your effort scais !!